# PHP how to make the value of the result display in textbox

Tags: php, textbox, expression, sign

I have 4 radio buttons `+`, `-`, `*`, `/` and I am planning to do if I select `+` it will add the result of the two textbox and display it to the 3rd texbox and so if I select `-` sign it will minus the two texbox and display it to the 3rd textbox and so on. Any help with this would be appreciated. [this is the picture](http://prntscr.com/8562ns)

```
 <html>
    <body>
    <?php
      function add($x,$y){

           $add=$x + $y;
           return $add;

       }
       function subtract($x,$y){

           $subtract=$x - $y;
           return $subtract;

       }
       function multiply($x,$y){

           $multiply=$x * $y;
           return $multiply;

       }
       function divide($x,$y){

           $divide=$x / $y;
           return $divide;

       }

    ?>
    <form action="#" method="post">
    Num1:<input name="num1"><br>
    <input type='radio'  name='express' value='add'>+
    <input type='radio'  name='express' value='subtract'>-
    <input type='radio'  name='express' value='multiply'>*
    <input type='radio'  name='express' value='divide'>/
    <br>
    Num2:<input name="num2"> 
    Result<input value='<?php



    ?>'>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
    <?php


       if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
           $x=$_POST['num1'];
           $y=$_POST['num2'];
           $z=$_POST['express'];
           if($z == 'add'){
               echo add($x,$y);  
           }
           else if($z=='subtract'){
               echo subtract($x,$y);

           }
           else if($z=='multiply'){
               echo multiply($x,$y);

           }
           else{
               echo divide($x,$y);

           }

       }

    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You should use Javascript, or stick to the submit(rather than radio) and calculate the whole set of values each time a submit(seemingly radios) is clicked.

Comment: I assume you are looking for the solution how to make your radio buttons work on click. This is can be achieved by using javascript function for your radio buttons. Basically, you can use pure javascript or something like jQuery for faster development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
   $Result = '';

   if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
       $num1    = $_POST['num1'];
       $num2    = $_POST['num2'];
       $express = $_POST['express'];
       switch ($express) {
        case 'add':
           $Result = $num1 + $num2;
           break;

        case 'subtract':
           $Result = $num1 - $num2;
           break;

        case 'multiply':
           $Result = $num1 * $num2;
           break;

        case 'divide':
           if(0 != $num2 ){
            $Result = $num1 / $num2;
          }
          break;

         default:
           break;
       }  

   }

?>
<form action="#" method="post">
Num1:<input name="num1"><br>
<input type='radio'  name='express' value='add'>+
<input type='radio'  name='express' value='subtract'>-
<input type='radio'  name='express' value='multiply'>*
<input type='radio'  name='express' value='divide'>/
<br>
Num2:<input name="num2"> 
Result<input value='<?php echo $Result;?>'>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I suggest you achieve it by using JavaScript and separate the PHP code from HTML code.

Comment: i tried like this but it says error was the trick is because u put ur <?php at the top instead of bottom i tried like this but not switch statement and echo $result and all i got is error ? and also can u explain y did u declare $Result='' whats the meaning of that

Comment: The $Result is a variable that represent the result. You should put the code into a file with a PHP extension like .php.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
<?php
  function add($x,$y){

       $add=$x + $y;
       return $add;

   }
   function subtract($x,$y){

       $subtract=$x - $y;
       return $subtract;

   }
   function multiply($x,$y){

       $multiply=$x * $y;
       return $multiply;

   }
   function divide($x,$y){

       $divide=$x / $y;
       return $divide;

   }


   if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
       $x=$_POST['num1'];
       $y=$_POST['num2'];
       $z=$_POST['express'];
       if($z == 'add'){
           $result=add($x,$y);  
       }
       else if($z=='subtract'){
           $result=subtract($x,$y);

       }
       else if($z=='multiply'){
           $result=multiply($x,$y);

       }
       else{
           $result=divide($x,$y);

       }

   }

?>
```

```
<form action="#" method="post">
Num1:<input name="num1"><br>
<input type='radio'  name='express' value='add'>+
<input type='radio'  name='express' value='subtract'>-
<input type='radio'  name='express' value='multiply'>*
<input type='radio'  name='express' value='divide'>/
<br>
Num2:<input name="num2"> 
Result<input value='<?php if(isset($result)){echo $result;} ?>'>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

If you have any question please ask...

Comment: @ShauiosbhaoiuAousiguosba keep total code in a single php file and give it extension .php

Answer (score 0):

Here is a jQuery version. I'm sure someone more adept than myself in jQuery could make a more savvy version:

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/pn1v1az7/4/

**jQuery:**

```
function CalculateVals(Obj)
{
    // Set default value as 0
    var Result  =   0;
    // Get the value of the checked radio box
    var UseOpr  =   $("input[name='express']:checked").val();
    // Get the value of input num1
    var n1      =   $("input[name='num1']").val();
    // Get the value of input num2
    var n2      =   $("input[name='num2']").val();
    // See if the value for one is numeric, if not make it 0
    var Num1    =   (!isNaN(n1))? n1:0;
    // Same as above
    var Num2    =   (!isNaN(n2))? n2:0;
    // Loop through to find the operator being used
    switch(UseOpr) {
        case('+'):
            // Using the plus like "+Num1" converts string to number, just in case...
            Result = +Num1 + +Num2;
            break;
        case('-'):
            Result = +Num1 - +Num2;
            break;
        case('*'):
            Result = +Num1 * +Num2;
            break;
        case('/'):
            Result = +Num1 / +Num2;
    }
  // Insert the mathematical result into box 3
  $("#result").val(Result);
}

// If the form changes
$("form").change(function() {
    // Run the above calculation function by passing the form as an argument
    CalculateVals($(this));
});
```

**Form:**

```
<form action="#">
    Num1:<input name="num1"><br>
    <input type='radio'  name='express' value='+' />+
    <input type='radio'  name='express' value='-' />-
    <input type='radio'  name='express' value='*' />*
    <input type='radio'  name='express' value='/' />/
    <br>
    Num2:<input name="num2" /> 
    Result<input id="result" name="result" value="0">
</form>
```